# Conditional adding running total calculation in google sheets query formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

As a result of my search on your site, I saw the topic "Adding running total to a query in Google sheets".
When I tried the suggested solution example, I couldn't get any results.
I opened a new topic because I wasn't sure if it would be right to write my question at the bottom of that page.

INFORMATION:
Google Sheets Query
Query data range sheet name: HAREKETLER
Query data range name: HAREKETLER
Result output sheet name: KASA
Condition reference cell: (KASA) B1
Formula cell address: (KASA) D1

EXPECTED RESULT:
The formula is expected to retrieve numerical values from the query data range based on the condition in B1 and calculate the running total for each row.

```
=arrayformula (EĞER(
QUERY(HAREKETLER; "SELECT L WHERE B = '"&B1&"' label (L) ''");DÇARP((DEVRİK_DÖNÜŞÜM((SATIR(
QUERY(HAREKETLER; "SELECT L WHERE B = '"&B1&"' label (L) ''"))<=DEVRİK_DÖNÜŞÜM(SATIR(
QUERY(HAREKETLER; "SELECT L WHERE B = '"&B1&"' label (L) ''"))))*
QUERY(HAREKETLER; "SELECT L WHERE B = '"&B1&"' label (L) ''")));(MUTLAK(İŞARET(
QUERY(HAREKETLER; "SELECT L WHERE B = '"&B1&"' label (L) ''"))))); EĞERHATA(1/0))  )
```

CURRENT RESULT:
The formula retrieves the desired number of rows based on the condition but shows #N/A instead of the actual values from the query data range.

What would be the modified formula to eliminate this problem?

Comment: `I opened a new topic because I wasn't sure if it would be right to write my question at the bottom of that page.` You did the right thing by opening this question. Two extra things: 1) you referenced a question that helped you but that question has two answers. Which of the answers did you try to use to create your own solution? 2) To help you debug this formula, we need your data.